# jar xf file.jar not working in windows 10

Tags: java, windows, jar

Not working in Windows 10:

```
> jar xf file.jar
'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: this is likely not related to the OS. Did you set your environment variables correctly?

Comment: You need to set your $PATH. Note that you can also unzip .jar files.

Answer (score 0):

In a PowerShell, you should first:

> $Env:Path+="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin"

Change `jre1.8.0_181` according to your installed Java Runtime Environment. For sanity check, you can print the updated path:

> $Env:Path

Then:

> java -jar -h

I still haven't figured how to get the `xf` subcommand to work though.